# Какие есть средства для написания книг на HTML и (!) CSS?

Tags: html, css, latex

Если вбить с google "написание книг на html и css", то он google, проигнорировав слово "написание", решит, что мне нужны книги по html и css и выдаст что-то в этом роде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перед тем, как стать фронтенд веб-разработчиком, я был активными пользователем LaTeX-а. Но одновременное отслеживание тенденций в мире фронтенд-разработки и мире TeX-а требует слишком больших затрат времени, а потому встал вопрос об унификации технологий, а именно об использовании HTML и CSS не только для веб-разработки, но и для написания книг (в основном, конечно, в формате PDF, но возможно понадобятся и адаптирующиеся к размеру экрана форматы).

Я знаю, что такое технологии существуют, но этом вопросе меня интересуют только те из них, которые позволяют использовать CSS (ибо на одном HTML без кодизврата что-то посложнее, чем монотонный набор абзацев, сделать трудно).

Comment: Вы б хоть пример такой книги дали))

Comment: Есть конвертеры LaTeX to HTML. Возможно, вам следует продолжить верстать книги на LaTeX, а потом просто конвертировать их.